# How to improve NetBeans spell checker?

Tags: netbeans, spell-checking

I love NetBeans and don't want to use phpshtorm instead. But NetBeans doesn't check my words when I write:

```
<div class="box sdsdsdsd"></div>
```

If I write it outside the class, it will say me that this word does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think that it would make sense to check CSS class names in 99% of the time, because usually you have CSS classes like xi-text-input-active or xiTextInputActive, both won’t be available in a spell checker, but both are legit css classes, or not, but if not it would have nothing to do with spell checking.

Comment: If I had written this line of code in phpshtom, it would have said me that "sdsdsdsd" is wrong word. I means this. But I want to make Netbeans to do this.

Comment: What would PhpStorm do with xi-text-input-active or xiTextInputActive? Would that be shown as correct or incorrect?

Comment: xiTextInputActive would be shown as a wrong word but if we write: "box_project_item" it would be checked as three different words

Comment: That's my point, there can be no right nor wrong. Why should be box_project_item correct but boxProjectItem not?
But if your still interested in such a feature I would suggest to file a ticket in the [Apache NetBeans Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS)